# How do I replace a complex string in a column (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Background**

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to replace the string: 'Connected to call (audio, video or screen sharing)'  with 'Connected', as well as replace 'Ended call' with 'Ended'

```
Connect                                                               End

Connected to call (audio, video or screen sharing)                    3/3/2020 2:00:01 PM
Ended call                                                            3/3/2020 2:05:00 PM
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Connect                                                              End

Connected                                                            3/3/2020 2:00:01 PM
Ended                                                                3/3/2020 2:05:00 PM
```

**What I have tried:**

```
df1 = df["Connect"] = df["Connect"].replace(Connected to call (audio, video, or screen sharing),      "Connected")
```

Furthermore, how would I replace strings if they are located within multiple columns? Connect and End? (As shown above)

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Are 'Connected to call (audio, video or screen sharing)' and 'Ended call' the only two possible values?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. _But how would I replace the strings of multiple columns?_ What does this have to do with multiple columns?

Comment: I am still very new and just trying to learn @AMC . I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numpy.select

```
# sample date
s = """Connect|End
Connected to call (audio, video or screen sharing)|3/3/2020 2:00:01 PM
Ended call|3/3/2020 2:05:00 PM"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='|')

# numpy.select with your conditions, choices and default value if condition is not met
df['Connect'] = np.select([df['Connect'].str.contains('Connected'), df['Connect'].str.contains('Ended')],
                          ['Connected', 'Ended'], df['Connect'])


     Connect                  End
0  Connected  3/3/2020 2:00:01 PM
1      Ended  3/3/2020 2:05:00 PM
```

Comment: @Yo_Chris I guess the issue OP had was with replacing `parantheses`. That needed to be escaped.  This solution just searches for anything that contains `Connected`. I don't think this was intented.

Comment: @MayankPorwal, my understanding of the question was the the OP wanted to replace the string "Connected to call (audio, video or screen sharing)" with connected. This solution does only search for "Connected" but can be replaced with any string.

Comment: Don't want it to be a big deal. Just saying that your solution kind of brushes away the main problem. It's more of a workaround which does not even bothers to tell OP the miss.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `parantheses` with `\` while replacing. That is what is creating problem.

So do something like this:

```
In [133]: df.Connect.str.replace("Connected to call \(audio, video or screen sharing\)", 'Connected')                                                                                                       
Out[133]: 
0     Connected
1    Ended call
Name: Connect, dtype: object
```

For all replacements together, you can do this:

```
In [142]: replacements= {'Connect' : {"Connected to call \(audio, video or screen sharing\)" : 'Connected', 'Ended call': 'Ended'}}                                                                         

In [143]: df.replace(replacements, regex=True, inplace=True)                                                                                                                                                

In [144]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[144]: 
     Connect
0  Connected
1      Ended
```

Comment: ok thank you, is there a way to also replace 'ended call' in the same command?

Comment: Can I upvote two? I thought only one answer could be upvoted?

Comment: Ok I read your comment about the answer, I see what you’re saying here. But I am not sure if it is polite to remove vote once it is set

Comment: Oh yes I have ! Thank you so much